# ¿Cómo referenciar un archivo js en angular?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, json, angular

Estoy tratando de referenciar una hoja de js en mi proyecto en angular, ya he referenciado los scripts dentro del archivo angular.json:

```
        "scripts": [
          "../ha-angular/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "../ha-angular/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "../ha-angular/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "../ha-angular/src/app/pet/js/imgur.js",
          "../ha-angular/src/app/pet/js/upload.js"
        ],
```

Pero aún así no funciona la aplicación en la parte html de mi componente "pet", acá está el [repositorio](https://github.com/pebeto/ha-angular), mi idea es usar una función en js para cargar imágenes a través de la página de imgur, tal como se aprecia en este pequeño [proyecto](https://github.com/carry0987/Imgur-Upload), ya he intentado referenciarlo con la etiqueta "script" en el index.html, así como también dentro del pet.component.html pero aún así no funciona.

Comment: Define "no funciona"

Comment: @PabloLozano como se puede apreciar en el repositorio que usa la api de imgur para cargar imágenes, la función en js se aplica y la imagen carga correctamente y te arroja el url que se aloja en el servidor, pero cuando yo copio el mismo codigo html y referencio los archivos js dentro de mi componente, solo se muestra el dragzone de las imágenes, más no me permite subir ninguna imágen ni nada por el estilo, al momento de hacer el debug, me di cuenta que no está referenciando a las hojas de js que supuestamente se deben referenciar con la etiqueta script.

Comment: Hola. La manera como estás referenciando la ubicación de los archivos es redundante (vas un directorio atrás para volver una vez mas a la raíz del proyecto) ya que el archivo `angular.json` está al mismo nivel que `node_modules` y `src`. Por lo tanto sería algo como: `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js` y así... Por otro lado; si "pet" es un componente, debería ser un directorio exclusivo para elementos que constituyen el componente, los js que estás llamando son librerías de terceros (supongo) y deberían estar ubicados en un directorio tal como: `src/assets/js`.